# How to read data from MSMQ in C# ? (please note - Data is not written in C# )

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, msmq

I am using nodejs, msmq and .net as technology stack in my project. I am collecting data from hardware using nodejs script and writing into MSMQ.
I want to read this MSMQ in .net but I am getting below error.
In addition I am not able to receive the message as well.

> Error
>         System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 
>          at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
>          at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
>          'objMessage.ConnectorType' threw an exception of type 
>          'System.InvalidOperationException'
>          'objMessage.Body' threw an exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException'

```
//Nodejs script
const msmq = require('updated-node-msmq');
const queue = msmq.openOrCreateQueue('.\\Private$\\EEG');
queue.send(records);
```

```cs
// C# code
if (MessageQueue.Exists(@".\Private$\EEG")){
    objMessageQueue = new MessageQueue(@".\Private$\EEG");
}
objMessage = objMessageQueue.Receive();
objMessage.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] 
     {typeof(Payload) });
var message = (Payload)objMessage.Body;
```

Comment: Please post an example content. From the error message, you are not sending valid XML.

Comment: Use the ActiveXMessageFormatter

Comment: @Fildor {"time":"2019-07-23 17:03:35","delta":0,"theta":0,"la":0,"ha":0,"lb":0,"hb":0,"lg":0,"hg":0,"attention":0,"relaxed":0,"stressed":0,"blinkStrength":0}

Comment: Try wrapping that json in an xml string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve the issue. Instead of using message.Body I have used message.BodyStream and converted that data into binary format. here's my solution.

```
   using System;
using System.Messaging;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace NeuroskyListener
{
    class Program
    {
        public static bool isRunning;
        private static MessageQueue messageQueue;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InitializeQueue();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void InitializeQueue()
        {
            string queuePath = @".\Private$\eegNew";

            if (!MessageQueue.Exists(queuePath))
            {
                messageQueue = MessageQueue.Create(queuePath);
            }
            else
            {
                messageQueue = new MessageQueue(queuePath);
            }
            isRunning = true;
            messageQueue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] {typeof(string) });
            messageQueue.ReceiveCompleted += OnReceiveCompleted;
            messageQueue.BeginReceive();
        }

        private static void OnReceiveCompleted(object source, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs asyncResult)
        {
            try
            {   
                MessageQueue mq =  (MessageQueue)source;

                if (mq != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        System.Messaging.Message message = null;
                        try
                        {
                            message = mq.EndReceive(asyncResult.AsyncResult);
                            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(message.BodyStream);

                            int count = (int)message.BodyStream.Length;

                            byte[] bytes = reader.ReadBytes(count);


                           string bodyString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
                            eegPayload lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<eegPayload>(bodyString);

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                           // LogMessage(ex.Message);
                        }
                        if (message != null)
                        {
                            //Payload payload = message.Body as Payload;

                            Console.WriteLine(message.Body);

                            //if (payload != null)
                            //{
                            //    receivedCounter++;
                            //    if ((receivedCounter % 10000) == 0)
                            //    {
                            //        string messageText = string.Format("Received {0} messages", receivedCounter);
                            //        LogMessage(messageText);
                            //    }
                            //}
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (isRunning)
                        {
                            mq.BeginReceive();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                //LogMessage(exc.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```